# I am not able to connect Netbeans to my Xampp(My Sql) Server. When I try to do so it shows "Communication failure error

Tags: java, xampp, netbeans-8, mysql-error-1064, mysql-connector

I have Netbeans V8.2 with the latest version of Xampp installed on my mac. Successfully installed Xampp and created a database and also added My Sql connecter 8.0 to Netbeans but when I try to connect it to my database it shows " Communication failure error, the last packed send successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packet from the server"

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/TEST";
       try
       {     
             Connection myconn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");           
            String str="insert into AddStudent values(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement myst = myconn.prepareStatement(str);
            myst.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
            myst.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
            myst.setString(3,jTextField3.getText());
            myst.setString(4,jTextArea1.getText());
            int i=myst.executeUpdate();
            if(i==1)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Student Added Successfully");

            }
       }    
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally mysql port in xampp is 3306 not 8080

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Here is how:
Uninstalled Xampp and then installed MAMP which is running on port 8889.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/TEST";
            try
            {
                Connection myconn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
              String q="insert into std values(?,?,?,?)";
              PreparedStatement myst = myconn.prepareStatement(q);
              myst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
              myst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
              myst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
              myst.setString(4, jTextArea1.getText());
              int res = myst.executeUpdate();
                if(res==1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "User Added Successfully");
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage());
            }        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

open a project in netbeans
click services tab
right click on database and click new connection
select MySQL(connector/J driver) click next
click test connection button
next,next,finish buttons.

go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
in select operating system select platform indipendant
download zip archive

unzip downloaded folder
copy mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar file
go to netbeans 
click on files tab, right click on project folder and paste the file

click projects tab
right click on libraries folder of the project and click Add JAR/Folder
go to the project folder and select mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar file and click open

Answer (score 0):

I have Apache Netbeans IDE 12.6 with the latest version of Xampp v3.3.0 installed on my windows. Successfully installed Xampp and created a database and also added mysql-connector-java-5.1.2.jar to Netbeans but when I try to connect it to my database it shows error unknown database.

this is code i am use

```
        Connection con = null;
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
```